# Riesz Representation Theorem for $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, schwartz-distributions, duality

The spaces $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (square-integrable functions) and $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ (1-periodic square-integrable functions, considered over the real line $\mathbb{R}$) are two subspaces of the space of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ and one can easily show that the sum $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$ is direct.

The duals of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ are isometrically isomorphic to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, respectively (Riesz representation theorem). Therefore, the continuous dual of the direct sum is simply $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$ in the sense that (1) an element $g_1 + g_2 \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$ defines a continuous linear functional over $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$ via
$$(f_1 + f_2) \mapsto \langle f_1 , g_1 \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} +  \langle f_2 , g_2 \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}$$
(which uses that both decompositions $f = f_1 + f_2$ and $g = g_1+g_2$ are unique), and that (2) any element of $(L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T}))')$ is of this form.

I would like to identify the subset $\mathcal{X}\subset \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ of functions $g$ such that
$$ L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})   \ni f_1 + f_2 \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) (f_1 + f_2)(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
specifies a continuous linear functional over $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$.
Clearly, by restricting it to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. setting $f_2=0$), we need to have $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Moreover, $\mathcal{X}$ contains any square-integrable compactly supported functions, but also functions that are not compactly supported but that have sufficiently nice asymptotic properties such that the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g (x) f_2(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is well-defined for any square-integrable periodic $f_2$ and defines a continuous functional over $L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

**Question:** Is there a way to identify the space $\mathcal{X}$ I am depicting? Can we reach any linear functionals over $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$ by doing so? I am also interested by generalization to other direct sums between spaces of periodic and non-periodic functions (e.g., $L^p$-spaces, or spaces of continuous-functions for the supremum norm).

Comment: To regard $\mathcal L^2(\mathbb T)$ as a subspace of the tempered distributions, you pull back to periodic functions on $\mathbb R$ and then integrate them against Schwartz functions?

Comment: $\mathcal L^2(\mathbb R) \oplus \mathcal L^2(\mathbb T)$ can be considered as $\mathcal L^2$ of the disjoint union of a line and a circle, with Lebesgue measure on each.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_1+f_2$ in the last displayed equation? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to define this sum that gives an element of $L^2(\mathbb R)$ (which is what you need here).

Comment: @LSpice Yes, that's right, I will had a precision about that.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Good point, $f_1 + f_2$ is not in $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ but still, so the notation $\langle g, f_1+f_2\rangle$ is a bit ambiguous, but I am considering the integration of the product $g \times (f_1+f_2)$. I am updating accordingly.

Comment: @MarkWildon It is not a typo but my way of writing is not very good, as Christian Remling also pointed out. I try to update for a better version.

Comment: @Goulifet: Thanks for clarifying. You can certainly not get all functionals $F$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)\oplus L^2(\mathbb T)$ in this way because $g$ is already determined by $F$ restricted to the first summand.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I completely agree and this is part of the problem. The first displayed equation specifies a linear functional, but the $g$ in the second one is definitely not in the direct sum. I hope to find the class of functions such that the second displayed equation "works" (gives a continuous linear functional over $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{T})$).

Comment: A good candidate would be the set of all functions $g\in L^2(R)$ for which $\sum_{k\in Z} g(\cdot+2\pi k)$ is in $L^2(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy This seems reasonable: it would be all the square-integrable functions such that the periodization is well-defined and specifies a square-integrable periodic function. The big question is then to clarify which functions can be periodized in this way.

Comment: Just so you are aware, any edit, even for a change of notation like $\mathcal L^2 \rightarrow L^2$, still bumps a question.

Comment: @LSpice Sure, I will remember that.